# Making multiple gradients using Less CSS

Tags: css, less

This is the first project I've used Less on, I want to make a series of buttons that have the same general structure but have different gradiated colours applied to them.

I have my default button style:

```
.button-regular (@origin: top, @start: #d2d2d2, @middle: #7a7a7a, @stop: #4d4d4d, @fallback: #3f4c6b, @border: #3c3c3c;) {
  border-radius: 3px; color: @white; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; height: 36px; font-weight: normal; padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px; text-align: center;
  background: @fallback;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, @start), color-stop(6%, @middle), color-stop(100%, @stop));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@middle', endColorstr='@stop', GradientType=0);
  border: 1px solid @border;
}
```

I want to overwrite the colours for each new instance of the button using something like the below:

```
input.lightBlue {
  .button-regular(top, #bfeef8, #40cdeb, #00bce4, #3f4c6b, #00b0d5;);
}
```

But when I create a button:

```
<input class="lightBlue" type="submit" value="Search">
```

The original (grey) colours still show. Is there a reason why the colours aren't overwritten using my new colours in this new button instance, and is there a better way to acheive what I'm attempting?

I'm using less.js to compile in-browser if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there should work alright, you just need to

### fix a typo:

- there is a semicolon (`;`) (after the last color) too much in your class definition

  ```
  input.lightBlue {
    .button-regular (top, #bfeef8, #40cdeb, #00bce4, #3f4c6b, #00b0d5);
  }
  ```
- you call for a variable `@white` in the mixin, where you just need to make sure you define it beforehand, or else just write `white` instead.

### some additional suggestions:

(I used some random settings for illustration).
You could do something like this

```
<input class="button default" type="submit" value="Search">
<input class="button green" type="submit" value="Search">
<input class="button red" type="submit" value="Search">
```

where you have a `button` class to define the general button appearance. Dunno, maybe something like this:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: .5em 2em .55em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.button:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

and in **LESS** you make some mixins for the color gradients. Something like this:

```
.gradient-mixin (@origin, @start, @middle, @stop, @fallback, @border) {
  background: @fallback;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, @start), color-stop(6%, @middle), color-stop(100%, @stop));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@middle', endColorstr='@stop', GradientType=0);
  border: 1px solid @border;
}

.button-make (@name:"default", @origin: top, @start: #d2d2d2, @middle: #7a7a7a, @stop: #4d4d4d, @fallback: #3f4c6b, @border: #3c3c3c;) {
  @classname: ~"@{name}";
  .@{classname} {
    .gradient-mixin (@origin, @start, @middle, @stop, @fallback, @border);
    &:hover {
    .gradient-mixin(@origin, lighten(@start,10%), lighten(@middle,10%), lighten(@stop,10%), lighten(@fallback,10%), @border);
    }
    &:active {
    .gradient-mixin (@origin, darken(@start,10%), darken(@middle,10%), darken(@stop,10%), darken(@fallback,10%), @border);
    }
  }
}
```

and then you call them for each color ... which will build your classes for each color for the buttons:

```
.button-make;
.button-make ("green", top, #7db72f, #87d918, #4e7d0e, #7db72f, #538312);
.button-make ("red", top, #ed1c24, #e93a3f, #aa1317, #ed1c24, #980c10);
```

here is a [**jsfiddle example of the output**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkf3q/).

But instead of defining all colors in the gradient by hand you can also make a more general mixin in LESS, that takes one color and transforms it to colors you use for `@stop`,`@start`,`@border`,... by using `lighten`, `darken` and other color operations.

Comment: A typo... damn. Thanks a lot for your answer, the additional info was excellent, certainly lots for me to think about.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand about this is that you want to overwrite your CSS with these buttons. All you have to do is create `divs` for your buttons or whatever else you are trying to do. I'll show an example here:

HTML

```
<input class="lightblue" type="submit" value="Search" style="/*style goes here*/">
```

CSS:

```
.lightblue {
border-radius: 3px; color: @white; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; height: 36px; font-weight: normal; padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px; text-align: center;
  background: @fallback;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, @start), color-stop(6%, @middle), color-stop(100%, @stop));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(@origin, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, @start 0%, @middle 6%, @stop 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@middle', endColorstr='@stop', GradientType=0);
  border: 1px solid @border;
}
```

So the point that I'm trying to make is that you just need a style for buttons. If you want to override this, then put the style in the HTML where I've shown. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I was hoping for a way of not duplicating all of that CSS for each button colour, there will be 10 different colours (in 3 different states, regular/hover/active) in all so I was attempting to avoid having 30x12 lines of virtually identical code.